# Pass new socket fd after fork

Tags: c, sockets

Is it possible to pass new accepted socket from the parent into the child process with C?

What is the correct way of doing it?

I know that the parent and child share the same open fd, but what about any new fd after the fork?

is sending the file descriptor over a Unix domain socket is the only way? is it possible to use shmget shared memeory instead and how?

I already tried Unix domain socket, but sometimes it fails with 'Bad file descriptor' in Mac.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: "but **sometimes** it fails with 'Bad file descriptor' in Mac." <- then you wrote a bug. Fix the bug, and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many commonly used multi-process servers don't use socket passing at all. A forking server forks the child only after the accept is done and thus inherits the child. A typical setup of a pre-forking server will inherit the listener socket instead and each child process will call `accept` by its own and handle the returned children.

Still, if file descriptors should be passed than SCM_RIGHTS with some kind of unix domains socket need to be used. Simple memory sharing is not sufficient since the socket file descriptor must actually be associated with the process in the OS kernel.

> I already tried Unix domain socket, but sometimes it fails with 'Bad file descriptor' in Mac.

If one gets an error it is probably a good idea to find out the cause of the error instead of simply looking for an alternative way to do it. Even if an alternative mechanism would exist it might simply show the same problems, because the problem might not depend on the specific mechanism at all.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for trying to help me! your words provided me with motivation and clear idea how others do it. After days of debugging it indeed was a bug that i created by wrong usage.